# How does github upload file feature works?

Tags: git, github

I came across a reddit post sometime back about how does github `upload a file` feature doesn't actually clone the project, instead it modifies the git history through low-level api. I'm unable to find that reddit post again :-(

I have a similar requirement to add & push a file to a git repo but cloning the entire repo is very costly (files are huge). Hence, I'm looking for low-level git api commands to use in order to add file to repository and push without cloning.

FYI - Shallow cloning won't work for me, since all the large files are located in the project root.

There are other similar questions, but have no solution - everybody says it's impossible. 
Considering github did it, there should be a way.

Comment: "Shallow" cloning usually refers to a clone that's shallow in terms of history; it still (typically) clones the entire current state of the repo, including files that may not have been added in the _very latest_ commit. It just avoids cloning down the changes from the entire repo's history, which can really add up over time.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub has the repository, so it's just a matter, on GitHub, of extracting the latest commit, writing the file, updating the index, and making a new commit.<sup>1</sup>  You can do the same thing on any server that has the entire repository: accept a file, check out the desired commit, add the file, and make the new commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>In fact, all you really need to do is read the commit into an index file with `git read-tree`, write a blob object with `git hash-object -w`, then update the index in place and use `git write-tree`, `git commit-tree`, and `git update-ref` to insert the new commit.  These plumbing commands do not require a separate work-tree directory.  It's *easier* if you have a work-tree directory, though, as that makes the user-interface commands work.